# What is the best approach to convert immutable objects to mutable objects (recursive)?

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion, mutable

Specifically, this problem has come to me when I make a request with AFNeworking with JSONkit and receive a (id)JSON with several arrays and dictionaries nested.

If I don't want to modify the data, I don't have any problem:

`self.myNSArray = [JSON objectForKey:@"result"];`

But if I want to modify the data I must to store it in a mutable variable:

`self.myNSMutableArray = [[JSON objectForKey:@"result"] mutableCopy];`

The last one doesn't convert nested arrays or dictionaries to mutable data; it works only for first level.

The only way that I have found is on this link [recursive mutable objects](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/recursive-mutable-objects); but I don't know if there is a best way to resolve this kind of problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the CoreFoundation function `CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy` with the mutability option `kCFPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves`:

```
NSArray *immutableArray = [JSON objectForKey:@"result"];
self.myMutableArray = [(NSMutableArray *)CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(NULL, immutableArray, kCFPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves) autorelease];
```

Comment: The ARC equivalent seems to be `CFBridgingRelease(CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(NULL,                             (__bridge CFPropertyListRef)(immutableArray),                                               kCFPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves));`

Comment: @omz Should this work for dictionaries, do you know? Can't seem to get it to convert.

Comment: It should. Please post a separate question with more details.

Comment: This [seems to return a `nil` value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34219638/937891) if the immutableArray has a `NULL` somewhere, do you happen to know of a workaround in those cases?

Comment: @Sathvik Property lists simply don't support `NSNull` values. If you want to serialize collections that contain them, consider using `NSJSONSerialization` or `NSKeyedArchiver`.

Answer (score 5):

On ARC:

```
CFBridgingRelease(CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(NULL, (__bridge CFPropertyListRef)(immutableArray), kCFPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves))
```

really worked. Thanks 
brainjam.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are taking care of `null` values in response string, otherwise it will return you nil which causes to horrible results.

(For Eg. Try mutataing response from
http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bQVoMjeJOW?indent=1)

Just place below line when converting API response to JSON Object.

```
responseString=[responseString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\":null" withString:@"\":\"\""];//To Handle Null Characters

//Search for below line in your parsing library and paste above code
data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

So there will be no null characters in your JSON object, hence no issue with using `CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy`.

Cheers!!