# CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy returns nil if any value is NULL

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, core-foundation

I am using the following `CoreFoundation` function `CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy:`
for converting the immutable objects to mutable objects.If any of the object is NULL the `CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy` returning empty .Is there any work around for this.

```
self.packageArray  = CFBridgingRelease(CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(NULL, (CFPropertyListRef)self.packageArray , kCFPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves));
```

[CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy fails to process array / dictionary containing NSNull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159205/cfpropertylistcreatedeepcopy-fails-to-process-array-dictionary-containing-nsnu)

sample code

```
 NSArray *immutable = @[ @"a", [NSNull null], @"c" ];      
 NSMutableArray *mutable = (__bridge 
   id)CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge 
        CFArrayRef)immutable, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers);
```

sample json response from [this link](http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bQVoMjeJOW?indent=2)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code sample for this?

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of workaround, I have solved this issue by below way.

Just place below line when converting API response to JSON Object.

```
responseString=[responseString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\":null" withString:@"\":\"\""];//To Handle Null Characters

//Search for below line in your parsing library and paste above code
data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

So there will be no null characters in your JSON object, hence no issue with using `CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy`.

Cheers!!